# Keyboard mapping issues when using Ubuntu RDP client into AWS Windows 8 box?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, keyboard, remote-desktop

I am using Remmina on my local Ubuntu 12.0.4 PC to run an RDP client session into a Windows 8 box running Amazon Web Services, with the US keyboard mapping selected in Remmina.  I'm having a problem with certain characters being translated into the wrong characters on the remote box.  For example, when I type a forward slash I end up with a dash on the remote PC.  ( "/" -> "-" ).

How can I fix this?

I found this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/216230/remote-desktop-to-ubuntu-has-wrong-keyboard-mapping

But the scenario covered in that thread has to do with RDP'ing into an Ubuntu box, not a Windows box.

UPDATE: I have just discovered that Shift+7 gets me the forward slash.  I'm including this information in case it's a clue to the real problem.

Comment: "/" is the forward slash. ;) What keyboard layout does Windows report you are using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks.  Fixed the slash reference.  The remote Windows box reports the Keyboard Layout as US.

Comment: And you're using an actual standard US keyboard?

Comment: It's from an old IBM Aptiva but I believe so.  I've never had this problem when SSH'ing into other boxes or working with apps on the local Ubuntu box itself.

Comment: Hmm weird stuff. Perhaps try a different RDP client and see if it behaves similarly..  Regardless, you should edit that useful information directly into your question, also include what you've attempted already to fix it, and hopefully someone will be able to nail it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Already did.  Tried xfreerdp because some people reported that if fixed the layout problems.  It didn't, but that's probably because they referencing the context of RDP'ing into a Linux box and not a Windows box.